# Unable to start T-SQL Debugging. Could not connect to computer ("*****")

Tags: sql, sql-server, debugging

When I try to debug an Stored Procedure using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I encounter this error message: Unable to start T-SQL Debugging. Could not connect to computer ("*****"). The dubugger cannot connect to the remote computer. This may be because the remote computer does not exist or a firewall may preventing communication to the remote computer. Please see help for assistance.
I really appreciate any help.

Comment: You need permissions to debug the instance of SQL Server you are connected to.  Can you not test this on a dev box?  Why are you trying to do this, to test performance issues?

Comment: What kind of permission, MS SQL Management Studio is connected and I can see data, but when I try to debug my Stored procedure I encounter that message

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3bxds0s(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: this one is for VS 2010 and has firewall tips: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/s0fk6z6e(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I have only got debug to work when I run SSMS as adminstrator

Comment: I did, but still not working

Answer (score 26, accepted):

SSMS needs to be able to find your SQL Server by DNS.  When you connect to the DB in SSMS, you can use (local), but (local) does not resolve on your network so the debug program can not find it.  Try connecting to localhost or your computer's name on the "Connect to Server" screen.

You should not have to run as administrator.

[image: SSMS Login Screen]

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to pay this forward, as after searching for quite some time I've yet to see anyone mention the problem that I encountered here.

I ran into this issue while connected to SQL using a SQL Server Authenticated user. Once I tried using a Windows Authenticated user I was able to debug without issue. That user must also be assigned the sysadmin role.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, thanks.

Comment: I'm using windows auth, though not able to debug. Any idea ?? i must be having sysadmin role?

Answer (score 0):

There's still problem in MSSQL 2012 if you want to debug a query connected to server via some defined alias. You need to connect to that server with the full name of the server first and then the debugger finds the server - otherwise it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to just go to the database-> security->login->right click on the login and add your name and check the service role as public and sysadmin. more reference [Unable to start T-SQL Debugging](http://sqltrends.blogspot.in/2011/02/unable-to-start-t-sql-debugging-could.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, I was connected to the server through RDC, and when connected to the instance I simply used '.', which failed. Then I tried 'SQL12P1' with and without port number, which failed. I then used 'localhost' and this solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

For local debugging (and I think for remote debugging too?) the Windows account *under which you are running SSMS* also needs to be set up as a SQL Server login and be a member of the SQL Server sysadmin role, in addition to this being required for the account (Windows or SQL Server) which you are more apparently using to connect to SQL Server, where these are different!

If not, you still get the same error message asked about in this question.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/s0fk6z6e(v=vs.100)

Answer (score -1):

Run Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio as *User Administrator* mode. You will not get this error while debugging. And You can debug stored procedure. This helps to solve my problem.